# Unable to find the JVM during `conda build`

Tags: java, r, conda, rjava

I've been trying to build an R package with conda this afternoon and seem to keep running into an issue with rJava. The build process can't seem to find the JVM. I'm running this under OSX 10.12.3 with Java version. Any thoughts on how to help the build process find the JVM?

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

$ conda build -c r r-rsubgroup

BUILD START: r-rsubgroup-0.6-r3.3.2_0
updating index in: /Users/cpd/anaconda/conda-bld/osx-64
updating index in: /Users/cpd/anaconda/conda-bld/noarch

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

cairo:      1.14.8-0
curl:       7.52.1-0
fontconfig: 2.12.1-3
freetype:   2.5.5-2
gettext:    0.19.8-1
glib:       2.50.2-1
gsl:        2.2.1-0
harfbuzz:   0.9.39-2
icu:        54.1-0
jbig:       2.1-0
jpeg:       9b-0
libffi:     3.2.1-1
libgcc:     4.8.5-1
libiconv:   1.14-0
libpng:     1.6.27-0
libtiff:    4.0.6-3
libxml2:    2.9.4-0
ncurses:    5.9-10
openssl:    1.0.2k-1
pango:      1.40.3-1
pcre:       8.39-1
pixman:     0.34.0-0
r-base:     3.3.2-1         r
r-foreign:  0.8_67-r3.3.2_0 r
r-rjava:    0.9_8-r3.3.2_0  r
readline:   6.2-2
tk:         8.5.18-0
xz:         5.2.2-1
zlib:       1.2.8-3

Source cache directory is: /Users/cpd/anaconda/conda-bld/src_cache
Found source in cache: rsubgroup_0.6.tar.gz
Extracting download
Package: r-rsubgroup-0.6-r3.3.2_0
source tree in: /Users/cpd/anaconda/conda-bld/r-rsubgroup_1490390655163/work/rsubgroup
+ source /Users/cpd/anaconda/bin/activate /Users/cpd/anaconda/conda-bld/r-rsubgroup_1490390655163/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl
+ mv DESCRIPTION DESCRIPTION.old
+ grep -v '^Priority: ' DESCRIPTION.old
+ /Users/cpd/anaconda/conda-bld/r-rsubgroup_1490390655163/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/bin/R CMD INSTALL --build .
* installing to library ‘/Users/cpd/anaconda/conda-bld/r-rsubgroup_1490390655163/_b_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_pl/lib/R/library’
* installing *source* package ‘rsubgroup’ ...
** package ‘rsubgroup’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** R
** data
** inst
** preparing package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded
JavaVM: requested Java version ((null)) not available. Using Java at "" instead.
JavaVM: Failed to load JVM: /bundle/Libraries/libserver.dylib
JavaVM FATAL: Failed to load the jvm library.
Error : .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rsubgroup', details:
  call: .jinit()
  error: JNI_GetCreatedJavaVMs returned -1
```

Comment: Does the JVM require any particular environment variables before it can be found?  If so, maybe your conda recipe needs to allow them.  See here: https://conda.io/docs/building/environment-vars.html#inherited-env-vars

Comment: Could very well be the case Stuart. I'll investigate this. Appreciate the pointer!